# I want to change the positioning of my plates in CSS in flexbox

Tags: javascript, html, css

Allow me to begin by saying I'm not set on using flexbox so if a different method has to be used, I'm open to it. I am making a JavaScript website which displays plates with questions and answers. Question length varies and so does the amount of answers - therefore the plates are not the same height.

They could be but I like the look of them not being so. The black image shows what it currently looks like and the white shows what I would like it to look like. I would like to be able to fully be able to customize the location of these plates to always be a fixed distance of `5px` appart.

Also if one plate is very long I'd like there to be the possibility of e.g. 3 small plates to be able to go on either side without them being changed in size but simply arranged in this messy clean look.

**Desired look:**

[image]

**Current look:**

[image]

(note: the change is the placement of plates, desired made through photoshop)

please note I have tried using `right` `left` `top` and `bottom` but they have no effect.

This is the code for one plate however the size of each plate varies along with the amount of answers, I also took out all the predefined and otherwise defined variables.

```js
<div className="Polls">
    <div className="Poll-1">
        text
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.Polls {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 5px;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: black;
}

.Poll-1 {
  width: 210px;
  height: 190px;
  margin: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-top-width: 1px;
  border-left-width:1px;
  border-right-width: 0.5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
}
```

Comment: Never, ever, post code as image. Create a [mcve] if possible.

Comment: If the order doesn't have to appear left to right, you could turn the flex direction to column instead of row, and control the height of the container. Otherwise I don't believe it is possible to achieve without some js intervention.

Comment: @toms could you give me an example of how to achieve this?

Comment: @flyingKite Ive elaborated in my answer below

Answer (score 0):

So here is my attempt using some js to sort your data.

Essentially i've created 4 flex-columns inside a flex-row container.

The JS essentially sorts your data between the columns, instead of outputting it all in one element. It cycles between the columns until there is no more data to output.

This way the flex column adapts to the height of the next element and you get your 'messy clean' look... i guess.

```js
// this to generate dummy poll data in an array of objects with various hights
var polls = [];
for(i=0;i<20;i++){ // generating 20 polls
 var randomHeight = Math.floor(Math.random()*50)+150; // setting them with random height property
 polls.push({text:'poll '+ (i+1),height:randomHeight})
}

// we loop through each element in the array of data, and assign it to different flex columns
// notice how each coloumn is named with a corresponding number
for(col=1,i=0; i<polls.length-1; i++) {
 var elm = $('<div class="poll"></div>'); // creating the generic element
  elm.text(polls[i].text); // injecting the content into the element
  elm.height( polls[i].height); // injecting height to illustrate different content size
 $('div#col'+col).append(elm); // eppending the element with it's content to the respective column
  col = col < 4 ? col+1 : 1;   // each time i check if I need to reset to the first column or move to the next one. 
  //You could also set a variable number of columns and generate them too.
}
```

```css
.container{
 display:flex;
 flex-direction:row;
 flex-wrap:nowrap;
 justify-content: start;
 background:darkgrey;
}
.polls {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: start;
  align-items: stretch;
  margin:2px;
  padding:1px;
  background-color: grey;
  width:210px;
}

.poll {
  height: 190px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  color: white;
  border: 2px solid white;
  background:black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="polls" id="col1">
  </div>
  <div class="polls" id="col2">

  </div>
  <div class="polls" id="col3">

  </div>
  <div class="polls" id="col4">

  </div>

</div>
```